# Error while using multipart/form-data in python

Tags: python, post, python-requests

I am trying to send a `post` request using `requests` library in Python.
The payload is a `form-data` so after searching I found to send a `request` with `form-data` I can use the `files` param.

```py
r = requests.post(url, files=body)
```

the problem is that the body contains a key `type` and every time I send a request it gives me this error

```
'Incorrect data', 'info': {'field': 'type', 'reason': 'empty'}, 'data': None}
```

But when I send the request using Postman, it works fine. so how to solve this problem?